# ShapeRenderer camera

Tags: camera, libgdx, shape-rendering

I'm working on platformer game (900x700). And I want to render rectangle (enemy) using ShapeRenderer but I don't see the renctangle.

```
    for(GameObject t : enemies){
                if(t instanceof Enemy){
                    t.update(Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime());
                    render.rect(t.getHitBox().getX(), t.getHitBox().getY(), enemies.get(0).getHitBox().width, enemies.get(0).getHitBox().height);
                }
    }
```

I understand that somehow I need to convert Screen coords to World Coords. I try to use

```
camera.unproject();
```

But I need **Vector3** as argument. So how can I get Vector3?

Comment: Just use your Vector2 coordinates and 0 instead of z-component.

Comment: Thanks for reply. But how I need to find out my Vector2 coordinates? I don't understand if I need to use  my whole game width and height?

Comment: We also don't understand this. Share all your rendering code including camera, batch and so on and then we'll be able to help you.

Comment: Ok, so you know where the problem was. But we couldn't help you anyway because you didn't give us all needed code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know the answer. I need to use `render.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);` and all works great! :)